# IdentityNotMappedException

Tags: c#

> System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: Some or all identity references could not be translated.

The error comes only one time after the registration of the application.

Answer (score 12):

IdentityNotMappedException is returned when a SecurityIdentifier can not be mapped, e.g. when a SID can not be translated to an NT user. 
This is usually caused by deleted users or no access to the domain controller who performs the translation. If it only happens once, then it is probably caused by intermittent domain controller connection failures or some sort of lag.

Comment: What if it happens repeatedly?