# Get the owner of a file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have encountered a error in VB.NET when I want to get the owner of a file.

This is my code.

```
Imports System.Security.AccessControl
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.IO
Dim fi As FileInfo = New FileInfo("X:\Temp\aa.txt")
Dim fs As FileSecurity = fi.GetAccessControl
Dim myuser As IdentityReference = fs.GetOwner(GetType(NTAccount))
Dim username = myuser.Value.ToString
```

and I got error:

```
System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException was caught
HResult=-2146233087
Message=Unable to translate some or all of the recognition references。
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
 System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceSids, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)
       in System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.Translate(Type targetType)
       in System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity.GetOwner(Type targetType)
       in Ts2.From1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 於 D:\Ts3\Ts1\Form1.vb: row 292
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Do these help ?  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2013/12/18/how-to-resolve-a-system-security-principal-identitynotmappedexception/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324831/identitynotmappedexception

Comment: yes,It's about AccountName...I change the computer to the same Domain,then,       It's run!

Comment: That is a pretty normal mishap with mapped drive letters like X:  You may well find an owner whose name is not known to your local OS.  Ultimately it is a network configuration problem, domains are important.

Answer (score 2):

ypu can easily get the owner of a file or folder using this ...

```
    Public Function GetFileOwner(ByVal fileName As String) As String
    Try
        Dim fi As New FileInfo(fileName)
        Dim fs As System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity = fi.GetAccessControl
        Dim owner As System.Security.Principal.NTAccount = CType(fs.GetOwner(GetType(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)), System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)
        Return owner.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function


Public Function GetDirOwner(ByVal fileName As String) As String
    Try
        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(fileName)
        Dim ds As System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity = di.GetAccessControl
        Dim owner As System.Security.Principal.NTAccount = CType(ds.GetOwner(GetType(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)), System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)
        Return owner.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks,I try it. It should have the same domain,too.